# Converting Python Request library to Nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, post, request

I am trying to convert the Python request code into Nodejs, however, I cannot find the corresponding usage in Nodsjs. I want to POST request using authentication looks like this

Python code:

```
resp = requests.post(url, auth=HTTPBasicAuth(username, password), verify=False)
print resp.content
```

When I use the code in Nodejs:

```
request.post(url).auth('username', 'password', false);
```

It is not working. I have no idea how to pass the auth in the post function. Any helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
var client = http.createClient(80, 'www.site.tld');
var user = 'user';
var passwd = 'pa$$';
var auth = 'Basic ' + Buffer.from(user + ':' + passwd).toString('base64');
var header = {'Host': 'www.site.tld', 'Authorization': auth};
var request = client.request('POST', '/', header);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, actually, I have a URL, do I still need to createClient?